# Copy HTML in Firefox or Chrome Inspector as displayed (maintaining indentation and formatting)

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to know if there is a way, either in the inspector (developer tools) of Firefox or Chrome, to copy html exactly like the dev tool is displaying it.

A lot of pages don't have well formatted code. If you go to "View Source Code" (CTRL+U) it's sometimes a mess. The dev tools of both browser do a very neat formatting and indentation, but I cannot figure out how to copy it.

For example, the code looks like this in the inspector:

**[Formatted code in Firefox dev tool]**

[image]

Pasted to sublime text, it is just one long line of code:

```
<div class="mod_customnav block"><a href="startseite.html#skipNavigation50" class="invisible">Navigation überspringen</a><ul class="level_1"><li class="verband first"><a href="vereine.html" title="Die Vereine im Badischen Sportschützenverband" class="verband first">Vereine</a></li><li class="geschaeftsstelle"><a href="oeffnungzeiten.html" title="Die Öffnungszeiten der Geschäftsstelle" class="geschaeftsstelle">Öffnungzeiten</a></li><li class="geschaeftsstelle"><a href="anfahrtsplan.html" title="So finden Sie uns" class="geschaeftsstelle">Anfahrtsplan</a></li><li class="formulare"><a href="waffenrecht.html" title="Waffenrechtliche Formulare" class="formulare">Waffenrecht</a></li><li><a href="sitemap.html" title="Die Website im Überblick">Sitemap</a></li><li><a href="kontakt.html" title="Kontaktformular">Nachricht an uns</a></li><li class="last"><a href="impressum.html" title="Impressum" class="last">Impressum</a></li></ul><a id="skipNavigation50" class="invisible">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

Comment: for this you would need to install a code formatter for sublime (or use an already implemented one, don't know this about sublime) . nearly every text editor has this feature.

Comment: Go to start of `<html>` tag and right-click `Copy->InnerHTML` it will copy everything excep for html tag settings, you can add them to beginning and add `</html>`to the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to copy the HTML in a formatted way. Though, at least for the Firefox DevTools exists a [feature request asking to allow to select the elements shown within the tree](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1343825), so you can copy them. I'm not sure, though, whether this is meant to copy the elements in a formatted way or also just copies the HTML source.

Having said that, there are online tools like the [Free Online HTML Formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html), which allow to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the feature request. As the author even wants to copy the "..." just as they are displayed by the DevTools it feels like he also means in a formatted way.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, after selecting some text, you can right click on it, then choose `View Selection Source`. Then, a new tab called `DOM Source Selection` is open with the selected HTML source highlighted. Mainly this is to quickly select the target elements you want. With virtually any IDE it'll format the selected DOM easily.

Comment: yes but if I select all of THAT and paste, the formatting is gone

Answer (score -1):

Theres an Sublime plugin which you can install Ctrl + O (shortcut to open search field for plugins i guess can't test now) "%Formater%" just type that in and install that HTML formatter plugin it should sort your code automatically. Or use Atom.io, Brackets

Comment: Only works if original code is well structured. It seems like you hardly read my question.

Comment: Theres an Sublime plugin which you can install Ctrl + O (shortcut to open search field for plugins i guess can't test now) "%Formater%" just type that in and install that HTML formatter plugin it should sort your code automatically. Or use Atom.io, Brackets

Comment: Even though I could not accept your original answer, your tip was quite helpful. I ended up installing CodeFormatter (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CodeFormatter) which works quite nice and is way easier than pasting code back and forth to something like an online html formatter.